# How to display badgeNumber at UIButton

Tags: iphone

I am developing iphone application, I have a home page, with buttons (icons), I have an icon for notifications, I want to display a badge number on it to determine how many new notifications user has. How I can do that for UIButton? I checked the SDK and found only UITabBarItem has badge value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this helpful: http://wiki.github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell/using-the-class

I used it to create my own badged button.